# How to pass list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to dynamically send a list object (as below) in JavaScript.

I am trying to setup a dynamic grid which accepts dynamic column names (instead of hardcoding the columns)

I am trying to create columnmap dynamically that will be used by grid, something like below,

```
columMap : {
    'Header' : [
        { title : "Title", field : "Title" },
        { title : "Created", field : "Created" },
        { title : "Created By", field : "CreatedBy.Account" }
    ]
```

I tried with `var list={field : 'Name',title:'Name'}`.. This works fine for one column but does't work for multiple columns. I tried array too, didn't work.. Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried this -> `var list = [{field : 'Name',title:'Name'}, {field : 'Name1',title:'Name1'}]` Is this something of structure that you are looking for?

Comment: How exactly did you "try array?"

Comment: Send an object/array where/how/when? Please be more specific. Maybe the MDN JavaScript Guide helps you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` represents an empty array

`[1, 2, 3]` is an array of three numbers

`[ { a: 1 }, { a: 1 } ]` is an array of objects

`[ 1, "a", { a: 3 } ]` an array does not care what type it holds

So...

```
var list = 
[
    {field : 'Name',title:'Name'}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was my mistake... I forgot to remove [] when I was passing my list object hence it was not able to set the value..

I got it resolved by passing list as below..

var list = [{ field: 'Name',title: 'Name' },{ field:'ContextNamePathRaw',title: 'Ownership Hierarchy'} ];

Thanks for your help!!!

BB